# TailwindCSS Unintentional transition delay

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css

I am building a website using angular 14.1 and tailwindCSS 3.2.4. Now please consider the following CSS

```
*, ::after, ::before{
  transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0ms;
}

.text-color{
  @apply text-neutral-900 dark:text-slate-50;
}
.text-color-hover{
  @apply hover:text-[#F1C203] dark:hover:text-[#F1C203];
}
```

It sets transition properties to any element on my site and with `text-color` and `text-color-hover` I simply define classes which represent colors for light/dark mode and hover state.

Now consider the following HTML

```
<div class="text-color text-color-hover font-normal mb-2 cursor-pointer">
  <span class="text-5xl">Films</span>
  <span class="text-5xl">>></span>
</div>
```

Now what happens is that I hover either of the span tags and both span tags change color. All good and well so far. However there is a delay in the color transition which is just as long as the transition duration defined in css. Obviously this is not intended. So how do I remove that delay?

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your issue correctly you must use `transition-duration: 0s` instead of `duration-dealy`. the `transition-delay` waits for some seconds before the transition effect starts but the `transition-duration` effect takes to complete.